# vue.js axios отправка формы

Tags: javascript, vue.js, form, axios

Пытаюсь отправить форму через axios, судя по devtools форма уходит, все заголовки и  request payload там есть, но в php файле принять данные не получается. Массив $_REQUEST понятное дело пуст, так как отправка идет через application/json, но и php://input почему-то тоже пуст...

```
var form = new Vue({
    el: '#consultation',
    data: {
        body: {
            name: null,
            tel: null,
        },
        errors: []
    },
    methods: {
        submit: function() {
            axios.post('form.php', {
                name: 'name',
                tel: '123456789'
            })
            .then(response => {})
            .catch(e => {
               this.errors.push(e)
            })
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: А при отправке данных Postman'ом, принять их получается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте упаковать инфу в `formData`. В методе `submit` попробуйте что-то вроде

```
let fd = new FormData();
fd.set(key, value);
axios.post('url', fd);
```

Тоже как-то страдал с отправкой формы, это выручило.

Comment: Странная ситуация, данные уходят, и в devtools во вкладке network -> preview показывается все как надо (в php у меня стоят echo для каждого элемента), но если там же кликнуть два раза на сам запрос к серверу, то массив POST пуст и ничего не выводится. По сути все что мне нужно это кинуть на почту, так-что на хостинг когда закину, попробую, если на почту будет уходить, то и пофиг.